# web application does not run on IE

Tags: php, ajax, internet-explorer, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using AJAX in form of jQuery for my client side scripting and twitter bootstrap for the layout, also using php for my server side scripting.

But the problem is the application runs fine on all other web explorers apart from Internet Explorer, does anyone have an idea to why this is happening, I cant even open a drop down in IE and I've tried both version 8 and 9.

here is a basic example of my jquery call to the server

```
function check_module() {
var option = $('#modules option:selected').attr('value');
$.post('modulesDropDown_1.php', 'option='+option,
    function(data){
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(obj);
        var name = $("#modules option:selected").text();
        $("#moduleCode").html(obj.allInfo.code);
});
return false;
}
```

i have a lot of these in my code, where the im calling to the server and returning it as json to the client... for instance i have a drop down which populates another drop down below soon as a value first drop down is chosen (AJAX), but the second drop down should then update the page based on the value but it just does not work in IE.

Comment: Without an error, or code example, its very hard to give pointers

Comment: i have just updated it with a sample code, does this help or you need more ?

Comment: It is always hard to answer these kind of questions when there is no example data of what could be inside of the JSON...

Comment: Need to see the JSON, and the HTML markup since you're talking about a display issue.

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of IE use a different mechanism for creating AJAX requests. Try something like this:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
```

although since it doesn't run on IE 8 and 9 that might not solve it.
It would help to see a snippet of code.

(Example from http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first)

Comment: do you mean you're using the jQuery AJAX handler or AJAX on a page with jQuery?

Comment: jqeury ajax handler, like the $.post